# Custom CSV export for last 1000 orders

Tags: magento-1.9, database, csv, export

I would like to export the last 1000 orders with following fields:
order id, customer email, first name, last name.

Is there an easy way to export a CSV like this? I do have access to PHPMyAdmin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the script to export last 1000 orders into csv format. To use this script just create `test.php` in your magento root directory and paste this code and run this script.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
require_once('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

$orders = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->getCollection()
    ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc')
    ->setPageSize(1000); // from here you can update the order count
$fp = fopen(Mage::getBaseDir() . DS . "exports_order.csv", "w+");
$csvHeader = array('Order ID', 'Customer Email', 'Customer First Name', 'Customer Last Name');
fputcsv($fp, $csvHeader, ",");
foreach ($orders as $order) {
    fputcsv($fp, array(
        $order->getIncrementId(),
        $order->getCustomerEmail(),
        $order->getCustomerFirstname(),
        $order->getCustomerFirstname()
    ));
}
fclose($fp);

echo 'exports_order.csv Successfully created.';
exit;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use "Export" function to export to CSV table **sales_flat_order**.

Comment: For some reason the sales_flat_order table is missing the last orders that I see in the backend. For example the last order in the BE is: 100002988 and the last entity_id in "sales_flat_orders" is 2772.. entity_id is the order ID right ?

Comment: entity_id is not the same thing as order number.
entity_id is just database table index, autoincrement number, and increment_id is your "human" order number, both visible for customer and in admin panel.